# How to assign a values to dataframe's column by comparing values in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames. One has rows for every five minutes in a day:

`df`

```
         TIMESTAMP              TEMP
1        2011-06-01 00:05:00    24.5
200      2011-06-01 16:40:00    32.0
1000     2011-06-04 11:20:00    30.2
5000     2011-06-18 08:40:00    28.4
10000    2011-07-05 17:20:00    39.4
15000    2011-07-23 02:00:00    29.3
20000    2011-08-09 10:40:00    29.5
30656    2011-09-15 10:40:00    13.8
```

I have another dataframe that ranks the days

`ranked`

```
      TEMP    DATE          RANK
62    43.3    2011-08-02    1.0
63    43.1    2011-08-03    2.0
65    43.1    2011-08-05    3.0
38    43.0    2011-07-09    4.0
66    42.8    2011-08-06    5.0
64    42.5    2011-08-04    6.0
84    42.2    2011-08-24    7.0
56    42.1    2011-07-27    8.0
61    42.1    2011-08-01    9.0
68    42.0    2011-08-08    10.0
```

Both the columns `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` are datetime datatypes (dtype returns `dtype('M8[ns]')`.

What I want to be able to do is add a column to the dataframe `df` and then put the rank of the row based on the `TIMESTAMP` and corresponding day's rank from `ranked` (so in a day all the 5 minute timesteps will have the same rank).

So, the final result would look something like this:

`df`

```
         TIMESTAMP              TEMP    RANK
1        2011-06-01 00:05:00    24.5    98.0
200      2011-06-01 16:40:00    32.0    98.0
1000     2011-06-04 11:20:00    30.2    96.0
5000     2011-06-18 08:40:00    28.4    50.0
10000    2011-07-05 17:20:00    39.4    9.0
15000    2011-07-23 02:00:00    29.3    45.0
20000    2011-08-09 10:40:00    29.5    40.0
30656    2011-09-15 10:40:00    13.8    100.0
```

What I have done so far:

```
# Separate the date and times.
df['DATE'] = df['YYYYMMDDHHmm'].dt.normalize()
df['TIME'] = df['YYYYMMDDHHmm'].dt.time
df = df[['DATE', 'TIME', 'TAIR']]
df['RANK'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'RANK'] = ranked[ranked['DATE']==row['DATE']]['RANK'].values
```

But I think I am going in a very wrong direction because this takes ages to complete.

How do I improve this code?

Comment: What would you want to happen if a date is missing in `ranked`?

Comment: `ranked` is derived from `df` so the dates in `ranked` is a subset of `df`. The dates should be the same in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can play with indexes to match the values

```
df = df.set_index(df.TIMESTAMP.dt.date)\
       .assign(RANK=ranked.set_index('DATE').RANK)\
       .set_index(df.index)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Does pandas use index to assign the values? Also, what does set_index(df.index) do?

Comment: @AkshayGaur So what we do there is (1) change the index to only the *date* of TIMESTAMP and then (2) create a new column named `RANK` using the `ranked` data frame with comparable indexes. Pandas automatically uses the indexes to match the values when assigning. Finally, (3) we set the index to be the initial one (which is still `df.index`, because `df` remains the original `df` throughout all these chain of commands, since we did not change it anywhere neither using`inplace` nor assigning a new value to it using `df = ..`, just *after* all these commands )